# Deleting HTML-Blocks with Regular-Expression

Tags: regex

I try to delete all HTML-Blocks which are closed.
I mean e.g. the following block is to delete, since it is closed `<> ... </>`

```
<b> some text </b>
```

But if it isn't closed (it lacks `</>`) , then it won't be to delete.
Below is a snippet of HTML-Code which is to process:

```
<div id="MyDiv">div,
  <strong>
    <span>span2, </span>                    <-- This is to delete
        <em> Some text for em
        <div> Some text for div </div>      <-- This is to delete
          <p><b>b,  <span id="MySpan"> Some text for span ...
```

After processing it should look like something as follows:

```
<div id="MyDiv">div,
  <strong>
        <em> Some text for em
          <p><b>b,  <span id="MySpan">span1,
```

I need a regular-expression statement to acomplish it. E.g. something as follows:

```
var sHTML = $('#MyDiv').html();
sHTML = sHTML.replace(/^<.*>.*?<\/.*>/ig, '');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please specify the context in which you will be using this regex--is it to perform operations on a live web page?

Answer (score 1):

```
<([^>]*)>[^><]*<\/\s*\1\s*>|<(\w+)\s+[^>]*>[^><]*<\/\s*\2\s*>
```

Try this.Replace by ``.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/79

Comment: Thanks, but what about in such a case: `<b style="z-index:1;"> text ... </ b >`

Comment: (<[^>]*>[^<]*<[^>]*>)  

Use this for the second case, run 2 regexes with vks's regex and then with this one or use OR

Comment: Ok, I've changed it as follows: `< *(.*)?([^>]*) *>[^><]*< *\/\1 *>` Thank you for your help. But I do not know, why I get a minus point? :(

Comment: I have not forgotten it, in order to mark it as correct, the user must have at least 15-points. I have only 6 points, hence I cann't mark it as correct :( , perhaps someone other would it done :)

Answer (score 0):

Nvm this works for every case or i am pretty sure it should

```
(<[^>]*>[^<]*<[^>]*>)
```

Comment: this will match <div>sdfsdfsdf</b> which is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your html is in a file called test.html, here's a perl one-liner:

```
perl -pi -e 's/<.*>.*<\/.*>//g' test.html
```

Comment: perl? I use jQuery or javascript. But I will try to understand and test your RegEx.

Comment: You can use it from the command line without understanding it.

Comment: But the RegEx will be called at run-time from jQuery in browser.